# Removing an unwanted commit coming from master branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I working on my branch (issue 393) after I finished I, checkout master branch to prepare for a rebase, then made a git pull, then check out 393 branch and then did this command. `git rebase master`

After that, I checkout Gitlab and I was stunned I made a mistake. There's a commit from another branch that wasn't supposed to be on my branch (393). I was researching how to remove a commit that I don't own but just wanted to remove them on my branch not totally on our codebase.

Here's the reflog:

```
6d5878e5 (HEAD -> remove-a-commit, origin/393-add-company-name-for-individual-account, 393-add-company-name-for-individual-account) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from 393-add-company-name-for-individual-account to remove-a-commit
6d5878e5 (HEAD -> remove-a-commit, origin/393-add-company-name-for-individual-account, 393-add-company-name-for-individual-account) HEAD@{1}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/393-add-company-name-for-individual-account
6d5878e5 (HEAD -> remove-a-commit, origin/393-add-company-name-for-individual-account, 393-add-company-name-for-individual-account) HEAD@{2}: rebase -i (pick): frontend additional fix done
f7ea5f82 HEAD@{3}: rebase -i (pick): backend can do crud on new user, updated reports view and csv download
3b615d25 HEAD@{4}: rebase -i (pick): New Wash/Bite Error Handling
cc988f50 HEAD@{5}: rebase -i (pick): completed: Teeth undo / redo
3630f840 HEAD@{6}: rebase -i (pick): Occlusal plane undo / redo
9436f9e7 HEAD@{7}: rebase -i (pick): fix: submit with incomplete landmarks
47004af0 HEAD@{8}: rebase -i (pick): add: Trim Redo
5fc03f49 HEAD@{9}: rebase -i (start): checkout 71064961
405847ee HEAD@{10}: checkout: moving from master to 393-add-company-name-for-individual-account
```

the

```
HEAD@{4}, 
HEAD@{5},
HEAD@{6},
HEAD@{7},
HEAD@{8},
```

The commit is from my boss. How do I remove that on my branch but won't get removed on the master, because that one is on master already.

### Update

I tried this `git rebase --onto 3b615d25 47004af0` but it has a conflict on a code that I didn't even edit.

Comment: Do you know what rebasing does? Can you show us the commit tree graph? Maybe also include how you want the tree graph to look like as well?

Comment: I didn't really think of how the graph will look like I was just told to do a rebase, so I did. Basically its the same as merge but the feature branch will be on top of the master. I did it right before but for some reason, this is the first time I encountered this problem and I don't have an idea how to fix this.

Comment: The resulting work tree might be the same, but don’t think a rebase is the same as a merge because they’re not.

Comment: on the articles the ive read they say its the same as merge. the commits from the feature branch will be added on top of the master instead of creating another commit for merging.

Comment: That than makes them different. Like you said result is the same, yes, but they achieve it in different ways.

Comment: Getting back to your issue, you say that a commit was included that was supposed to be in your branch, why was it there to begin with?

Comment: at first I tried to squash a commit. so on the same branch I tried to `git rebase -i <sha>` on the interactive rebase I marked the commit that I wanted to squash then exit and saved, after that i did a git reflog the commit that wasn't mine was included. after i got lost.

Comment: im confused now. so git rebase is not totally the same as merge? thought rebase is puttting the commits infront of master. and merge is creating a new entirely commit. they way they do it technically i dont know if thats what ur asking

Comment: It doesn't really matter about merge vs rebase. Just know they work differently. Also you mention that the reflog mentions a commit that wasn't yours, but a reflog isn't the history. `git log` shows that. The reflog shows when the head moves.

Answer (score 2):

Reverting the commit on your branch instead of rebasing it could help. It will cancel out changes on your branch, but will not delete any code:

`git revert <SHA ID of the commit you want to cancel>`

Edit: As mentioned by @RomainValeri, it will no delete any commit from your git repo (that is why you can confidently revert without any fear of losing code). It will create a new commit that cancels out (reverts) the changes of the specified commit.

Comment: doesn't work. tried doing on a single commit it's still there

Comment: @aRtoo I'm afraid you misunderstood what `git revert` is expected to do. It does **not** modify or delete the given commit in any way, it creates a *new* commit at the current tip of the tree, containing the exact reverse of what said commit brought in. For example, if commit `abcd1234` added some specific line, the revert command will create a new commit deleting that same line. The resulting code after this history is the same as if both commits had never been there, yes, but they're still present.

Comment: ohh I get it now. but I don't think that this will work because the bad commits are in the middle. if I dot `git revert <working commit sha before bad commit>` then I also lost the work that I currently committed. hope it makes sense.

Comment: @aRtoo you should not lose the work that is currently committed, but only the work in the commit @```<SHA ID of the commit you want to cancel>
```